# arduino.h: 48:17: fatal error: sam.h: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to compile a simple new project ('hello') for the Arduino M0 Pro. I have created a new project in visual studio 2015 (using vMicro).

But I get the error:

```
hello.ino: In file included from

arduino.h: 48:17: fatal error: sam.h: No such file or directory
   #include "sam.h"
   compilation terminated
```

Through the Arduino IDE - board manager I have installed the cores for Arduino SAM Boards and SAMD Boards. Currently it is on Arduino IDE: v1.6.18, SAM: v1.6.11 and SAMD: v1.6.15 (the newest version at time of writing).

The strange thing is that I do see that the project has included this file, as it is shown in the file tree of External Dependencies, see screenshot.

[file tree showing sam.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASIqh.png)

I have also checked the include paths in the 'hello.vcxproj' file. I have cut out the list below:

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\libraries
$(ProjectDir)..\libraries
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\cores\arduino
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\cores\arduino\avr
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\cores\arduino\USB
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\variants\arduino_mzero
$(ProjectDir)..\hello
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\CMSIS\Include\
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.3
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.3\arm-none-eabi
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.3\bits
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.10\system
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\avr
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\usb
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.8.3\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\CMSIS\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\component
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\instance
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\pio
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\4.5.0\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\component
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\CMSIS\include
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\component
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\instance
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\pio
$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\CMSIS\CMSIS-Atmel\1.0.0\CMSIS\Device\ATMEL\samd21\include\component
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Even when I just open a completely new project in the Arduino IDE and try to compile it for Arduino M0, I get the exact same error!

I am stuck at this point. I've tried, as suggested at some other websites, de-installing SAM, de-installing SAMD, changing versions of either, but no luck.

Comment: reinstalling the Arduino IDE and packages/libraries solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the specific solution was to delete the C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Arduino15 folder and reinstall the board packages I needed through the Arduino IDE Boards Manager.

Note this will not impact any libraries or other changes you have made in the IDE.